# Nuxt 3: How to use useHead() with async data fetched inside useAsyncData()

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, strapi, nuxtjs3

In my component's `<script setupt>` I am fetching data from my CMS (Strapi v4) inside `useAsyncData`, since the given route is pre-rendered server-side. In a second step I want to use the fetched data inside `useHead()` but the the title is either undefined or the application breaks.

```
<script setup>
const { find } = useStrapi4();

const { data } = await useAsyncData(
    "posts",
    () => find("posts"),
);

useHead({
    title: data.data[0].attributes.title,
})
</script>
```

Is there away to achieve this, without integrating `useHead()` in `useAsyncData()`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Call the useHead() composable after the variable is loaded.

For example.

```
<script setup>
 const { find } = useStrapi4();
 
 const loadData = async () => {
    const { data } = await await useAsyncData('posts', () => find('posts'));

    useHead({
      title: data.data[0].attributes.title,
    });
  };

loadData()

</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had a similar solution before but was hoping for a way to keep `useHead()`separate. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using useHead() outside of useAsyncData, try the data.value:

```
<script setup>
  const { find } = useStrapi4();
  const { data } = await useAsyncData(
      "posts",
          () => find("posts"),
      );
    
  useHead({
      title: data.value.data[0].attributes.title,
  })
 </script>
```

Hope that helps.